# 'socat' not displaying incoming UDP packets, but Wireshark does

Tags: networking, iptables, wireshark, netcat, socat

The link is an image of a [Wireshark dump](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zDv69.png) of an incoming 60-byte Ethernet frame which contains a UDP packet. The packet payload is the single word 'hello' (sorry, I don't have enough rep to paste the image directly).

Problem: I can't get `socat` or `nc` to read and display this packet (this isn't entirely true; see #1 below).

I run the reader as:

```
$ socat UDP:192.168.50.129:5000 -
```

I've tried various different UDP-related address formats as well as this one. The writer is run as:

```
$ socat READLINE UDP:192.168.50.132:5000
```

**Question: how do I display this incoming packet, preferably as the single word`hello`?**

There are unfortunately some complications:

#### #1

If I run the reader as `# socat INTERFACE:ens4f0 -` then I *do* get a display of the incoming frame (it's displayed twice, for some reason). There's some binary output and then the word `hello`. However, I can't do this, as there will eventually be other processes using this interface, so I need to understand what's going on

#### #2

The incoming frame actually has a dst IP address of `192.168.50.132`; the firewall is set to convert this to `192.168.50.129`, which is the address the reader is listening on:

```
  # iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i ens4f0 -j DNAT --to 192.168.50.129
```

The Wireshark output shows the incoming packet before this conversion, so shows the dst IP address as `192.168.50.132`. I don't really know whether or not this is working - can I get `socat` to produce a hex dump of what it is actually seeing on `ens4f0`?

#### #3

This is the difficult one, but I'm hoping that it's not related. This is actually a loopback test: a single frame goes out on `ens4f0`, is looped back by external hardware, and is returned unmodified to `ens4f0`. The NIC has IP address `192.168.50.129`. I have an `ip neigh add` command which routes accesses to `192.168.50.132` out from `ens4f0` to the external hardware; the packet is returned unmodified, which is why I need the `iptables` command to convert the dst IP address back to the `ens4f0` address.

Comment: Hi @A.B: for XY, the actual problem is basically #3: carry out a loopback test using a single network card. The loopback goes through external test kit, but can be considered to be a simple Ethernet loopback cable. I force the traffic to go  externally by defining a dummy IP address (132) and `ip neigh add`. I know this works, and the external traffic is returned to `ens4f0`. The problem is then to read the packet. I'm hoping to do this with NAT, by changing the dummy address (132) to the real IP address of the card (129). However, I don't think NAT is working.

Comment: I deleted my comment because I think every of the 3 points have problems. socat usage, using stateful nat with a stateless nat in front of it, using looped back traffic with same addresses all this in a context of nat. description doesn't match the command. eg: "the firewall is set to convert this to 192.168.50.129" doesn't match "--to 192.168.50.132" . And for the goal I was asking: for what application will that be useful, not how it's done, but why it's done.